# How to locate the element identified by ID and the value is same in two different pages using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to locate the element identified by ID and the value is same in two different pages using selenium webdriver.

The problem may be the time to load the page. I have given the implicitly wait and pageloadtimeout for 2 mins. But we are facing the same problem.

Comment: Try to use Thread.sleep command

Answer (score 0):

You can wait till an element in other page (navigated away from current page) gets enabled/loaded after clicking an element in the current page. Though you have give good amount of time to wait (need to be increased for this scenario), it needs to be looked by developers to optimize it, as 2 minutes would be very huge amount of time for page loading.

Answer (score 0):

So if you are wanting to find the second element, you could find the first and then navigate to the other page and then wait for a staleElementReference before trying to find the new element.

Here's something you could try:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('foo') # Or locate the element however you are currently
# Do your navigation stuff here.
while True:
    try:
        element.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        time.sleep(5)
    except StaleElementReference:
        break
element = driver.find_element_by_id('foo')
```